# bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress - Invalid amount

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

Does something know what's exactly validation of amount parameter for bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress command?

Example:

`bitcoin-cli -testnet sendtoaddress tb1ql7w62elx9ucw4pj5lgw4l028hmuw80sndtntxt 0.0105122802`

```
error code: -3
error message:
Invalid amount
```

If I send amount with less symbols after comma (0.010512280) it works.

Answer (score -1):

Bitcoin supports only 8 decimal places, you are using 10

> If I send amount with less symbols after comma (0.010512280) it works.

It works because it ends with 0, so it is basically 8 decimal places, but if you set something like 1 for sample you will have the same issue

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:FAQ#How_divisible_are_bitcoins.3F